# AWS Rule not Posting to DynamoDB - Raspberry Pi

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been searching high and low for a solution to this. I'm uploading sensor data from a Raspberry Pi to AWS Shadow, I need this AWS Rule to trigger when the shadow document is accepted, then store that data in DynamoDB.. I'm new to this...
Nothing is happening.. The shadow updates, but no luck getting it to DynamoDB:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your IAM role that your action is using, as well as the full IoT rule? It's possible you have a configuration problem as well as a permissions issue.

Comment: @SamRastovich [IAM](https://i.imgur.com/0JDbKoq.png) [Rule](https://i.imgur.com/1h9YZss.png)

Comment: Why your Rule query statement is `Select * from "#"`?

Comment: @hoangdv, it was "$aws/things/Sprinkler/shadow/update/accepted" but that wasn't working, I saw another thing online where they used '#', so I thought I'd try it